# Unity - Instantiated prefabs do not adapt to UI Layout

Tags: unity

I have a small container, where I want listed a series of buttons. I try to fill them at Runtime like this:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class FillWithGearData : MonoBehaviour {
    public Transform SelectGearButton;
    public Transform GearPanel;

    void Awake() {
        Transform button = Instantiate(SelectGearButton, new Vector3(0, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity) as Transform;
        button.SetParent(GearPanel);

    }
}
```

But the buttons added at Runtime are not adapting to the Layout, even though the ones added before runtime seem to adapt without a problem.

Demo:

[image]

What is going on?

Comment: Have you tried passing false to SetParent's second parameter ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your clone button's scale is Zero. Set its scale to one after instantiating it.

```
public GameObject SelectGearButton;
public GameObject GearPanel;

GameObject button = Instantiate(SelectGearButton, new Vector3(0, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
button.transform.SetParent(GearPanel.transform);
button.transform.localScale = Vector3.one;
```

Comment: That did not work :(

Comment: Yea, that answer one minor mistake, well, I'd suggest to use `GameObject`

Comment: Check the edits

Comment: The issue was that changing the localScale had to be done AFTER setting the parent. Maybe a bug in Untiy? I am unsure, but thanks for the answer in any case! :)